# decode python binary string but not ensure ascii symbols

Tags: python, unicode

I have a binary object:

```
b'{"node": "\\u041e\\u0431\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435"}}'
```

and I want it to be printed in Unicode and not strictly using ASCII symbols.

There is a hacky way to do it:

```
decoded = string.decode()
parsed_to_dict = json.loads(decoded)
dumped = json.dumps(parsed_to_dict, ensure_ascii=False)
print(dumped)

>>> {"node": "Обновление"}
```

however the text will not always be parseable as JSON, so I need a simpler way.

Is there a way to print out my binary object (or a decoded Unicode string) as a non-ascii string without going trough parsing/dumping JSON?

For example, how to print this `b'\\u041e\\u0431\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435'` as `Обновление`?

Comment: If it may not be parsable as JSON… then what *is* it?

Comment: It's not a string, it's a bytes object.

Comment: @deceze It's not unclear what he's asking IMO. They want to remove the escape backslashes to get that result. They're saying they've found a way in the case that it's a json string, but they want a method in the general case.

Comment: @FHT Sure, but this example looks like JSON. Both JSON parsing and AST-literal parsing work on that, yes. But if the concern is that in some cases it may not be valid JSON… well then, what *will* it be? Valid Python which works with AST? Or something entirely different?

Comment: I guess you could do `data.decode('unicode-escape')`. But I'd be wary of recommending that without knowing what variations are possible in the input data.

Comment: only for display ascii, after t = json.loads(target), print(t['node'])? decode for?

Comment: @Vin That won't work if the target doesn't contain valid JSON.

Comment: @PM2Ring Yes! this is exactly what I need, thanks! The input is just what I specify a couple of function calls earlier, so it is completely controlled. The variations would include strings or JSON objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `bytes` string like

```
b'\\u041e\\u0431\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435'
```

has been encoded using Unicode escape sequences. To convert it back into a proper Unicode string you simply need to specify the 'unicode-escape' codec:

```
data = b'\\u041e\\u0431\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435'
out = data.decode('unicode-escape')
print(out)
```

**output**

```
Обновление
```

However, if `data` is already a Unicode string, then you first need to encode it to bytes. You can do that using the `ascii` codec, presuming `data` only contains ASCII characters. If it contains characters outside ASCII but within the range of `\x80` to `\xff` you may be able to use the 'latin1' codec.

```
data = '\\u041e\\u0431\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435'
out = data.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work so long as all the escapes are valid (no single `\`).

```
import ast
bytes_object = b'{"node": "\\u041e\\u0431\\u043d\\u043e\\u0432\\u043b\\u0435\\u043d\\u0438\\u0435"}}'

unicode_string = ast.literal_eval("'{}'".format(bytes_object.decode()))
```

output:

```
'{"node": "Обновление"}}'
```